# Spring neo4j template loading recursive nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Neo4jOperations to query neo. Spring is getting the node and its parent node but is also getting the children of the parent which obviously I am not interested in. I only want node's direct parent and children.

```
@Repository
public class PracticeAreaRepository {

@Autowired
Neo4jOperations template;

public PracticeArea get(String uuid){
    PracticeArea practiceArea = template.findByIndexedValue(PracticeArea.class, "practiceAreaId", uuid).singleOrNull();
    template.fetch(practiceArea.getChildren());
    template.fetch(practiceArea.getParent());
    return practiceArea;
}
}
```

PracticeArea.java

```
@NodeEntity
public class PracticeArea {

@GraphId
private Long id;

private String name;

@Indexed
@GraphProperty(propertyName = "practice_area_id")
private UUID practiceAreaId;

@RelatedTo(type = "HAS_PARENT_PRACTICE_AREA", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
PracticeArea parent;

@RelatedTo(type = "HAS_CHILD_PRACTICE_AREA", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
Set<PracticeArea> children;

/* Getters & Setters */ ....
}
```

How do I stop Spring neo4j to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Then don't call:

```
template.fetch(practiceArea.getParent());
```

Or actually that call shouldn't fetch that's parent's children if that parent was not already loaded in your current thread.